# How do I throw an exception with Hibernate when a field is changed?

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to somehow denote certain fields in my beans as Immutable, such that if an attempt at saving a different value than the one in the database is made, an exception is thrown.

I understand that in the mapping file, I can set mutable="false", but this does not throw an exception like I had hoped.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a Hibernate Interceptor was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can move your Hibernate annotations from getters/setters to fields.  You can then implement whatever checks you need in the setter without impacting Hibernate.  For example,

```
@Column("foo_column")
private String foo;

public void setFoo(String foo) {
    if (this.foo != null)
        throw new YourException("cannot change foo");
    this.foo = foo;
}
```

Comment: Why bother even having a setter? Just remove it so that the value cannot be modified at all

Comment: @MrWiggles I could have read too much into the question, but my assumption was that it should be possible to set the value once and that it would be immutable only after the entity was persisted.  I suppose you could do that with a constructor arg and eliminate the setter.

Comment: The full use case is that the client will send the object to the server through Spring, which then saves it using Hibernate. Once persisted however, some properties of this object cannot be changed. A check on the setting is an interesting idea, but ultimately won't work for me because I have some cross field validations that may require foo. And since these objects come from the client, the previous foo value will not be in memory.